# A way to show multiple Google Calendars as busy?

Tags: google-calendar

I use my Google Calendar everyday. I have multiple layers/calendars relating to my different responsibilities. When scheduling an appointment with a group of people, it would be most efficient for me to be able to simply send them a view of my filled out schedule but only with busy/not busy information.

I know this is possible with individual calendars. How can I allow for them to see the multiple calendar view that I do, but without the details of my schedule?